# my API runs properly in local device but once I run it in production with HTTPS I encounter an server error 500

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-rest-framework

This is the code for my views.py

```
class FetchCustomerUsingQRView(APIView):
authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

def get(self, request):
    code = request.data.get('unique_code')

    try:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(unique_code=code)
        print(customer)
        if customer.already_claimed == True:

            return Response({
                'message': 'You have already claimed',

            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        data_serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer)
        return Response({"data": data_serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    except Exception as e:
        return Response({
            'message': 'invalid unique code',

        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is working properly in localhost and I also try to run it in my virtual machine localhost and works perfectly but I receiving an error when running in production.

my Settings already set to

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not setting DEBUG to True in order to check what the trouble is? In case you are just deploying the service, it's the easiest way to do it.
Or if you are using Ubuntu to deploy, check logs via journalctl or another way.